# UIButton Alternate border

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, objective-c-category

I had to make border and adjust insets for a number of buttons, So I wrote a category class to UIButton to add border and adjust edge insets.

Here is my code for ui button catgory

```
@implementation UIButton (BorderAndEdgeInsets)

- (void) addBorderOnSides:(UITableViewcellSides )sides
               withColour:(UIColor *)colour
                  ofWidth:(float)width{

    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.backgroundColor = [colour CGColor];
    if(sides & Top)
    {
        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, width);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }

    if(sides & Right)
    {
        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - width, self.frame.origin.y, width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }
    if(sides & Bottom)
    {
        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.size.height - width, self.frame.size.width, width);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }
    if(sides & Left)
    {
        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, width, self.frame.size.height);
        [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    }
}

- (void) adjustImageAndTitleSpacings{
    [[self titleLabel] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [self setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 20, 0)];
    [self setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, -15, 0, 0)];
}
```

And this is my usage for the buttons:

```
int leftboundary = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *tab in tabDetails) {
        UIButton *tabButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftboundary, 0, 130, 66)];
        leftboundary += 130;
        [[tabButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
        [tabButton addBorderOnSides:Right withColour:[UIColor darkGrayColor] ofWidth:2];
        [tabButton addBorderOnSides:Top withColour:[UIColor whiteColor] ofWidth:5];
        [tabButton adjustImageAndTitleSpacings];
```

But in my output, the top white border is only on alternate buttons, whereas the right border is consistent on all buttons.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with some more contrast colors, and different width size? Can you attach some screenshot with current result?

Comment: SO did not allow me to attach image. But here is the google drive link to the screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9mHSqfBw59UTzNUcFlic0lXSm8/edit?usp=sharing

Yes I did try for different widths and colours. No use. Also